# Ant build script with embedded javascript

Tags: javascript, ant

I have the following ant task that has embedded javascript.  I'm trying to read the value of a property in my build.properties file but the following doesn't seem to work.

```
    <target name="analyze">
        <script language="javascript">
        <![CDATA[
                importPackage(java.lang);
                var path = "${FOOBAR_HOME}";
                System.out.println(path);
        ]]>
        </script>
    </target>
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: That worked....why did you remove your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your build.properties file is loaded before the script task using a [`loadproperties` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadproperties.html) or equivalent, then you could use something like:

```
var path = project.getProperty("FOOBAR_HOME");
```

or even just

```
var path = FOOBAR_HOME;
```

in the javascript. This is from the examples in the [`script` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html) docs.